# jquery .parent() to target parent li of ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi im just learning jquery

so basically im making a navigation with a drop down menu.

my problem is that i have my navigation hover to make the background #222, but once i move my mouse down to the menu that has now dropped down, the hover effect goes away.

here is the jquery

```
$('.navi li ul').each(function() {
    $(this).hover(
    function() {
        $(this).parent('li').css({ 'background-color' : '#222',
                               'color' : '#FFFFFF'});
    },
    function() {
        $(this).parent('li').css({ 'background-color' : '',
                               'color' : '#0085ac'
                             });
    });
}); //end ul parrent hover
```

the html is

```
            <ul class="navi">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">logos</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Business Cards</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Websites</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" style="background-image:none;">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
```

as you can see i have my ul inside the li, basically i want the parent li to stay in its hoverd state while browsing the menu that has dropped down.

bonus points if you can show me how to put a 250ms delay on the hover out before it changes back to normal state

edit: just to clarify, the above jquery is not working to keep my parent li in its hoverd state

Comment: can you please put this in a jsfiddle?

Comment: i used a dropdown plug in so im not sure i can..

Comment: just use .parent() don't put li inside

Comment: digitalerawebdesign.com/test/index.html

here is a demo, using the original jquery

Comment: what if i did something like, if ul is visible, parent li = style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( ".navi li" ).has( "ul" ).mousemove(function(){
    $(this).css('background','#222');
    });
    $( ".navi li" ).has( "ul" ).mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).css('background','#fff');
    });
});
```

and to avoid any conflict with :hover in css  just add !important

```
.navi li:hover{
   background : #222 !important;
}
```

Comment: bad approach to fix this problem.

Comment: this works but when you mouse leave, half the time it stays in hover styleing

Comment: digitalerawebdesign.com/test/index2.html

Comment: try to play around my updated answer. and for delay use   $(this).delay(250).css('background','#fff');